# All combinations of properties in an array

Tags: javascript, combinatorics

Okay, I have been breaking my head about this for the last couple of days. What is the neatest (anything without HUGE overhead) way to generate an array of all possible combinations

```
var input = [
    {a: 1}, {a: 2, b: 3},
    {b: 4}, {b: 5}, {a: 6}
];
```

So what I wish to generate is the following:

```
var output = [
    {a: 1}, {b: 4}, {b: 5}, {a: 6},
    {a: 1, b: 4}, {a: 1, b: 5},
    {a: 6, b: 4}, {a: 6, b: 5},
    {a: 2, b: 3}
];
```

The thing is though that in my specific case I am talking about 4 properties (and I actually need to generate a separate array for each set of different property sets, however those are both things I should be able to implement myself later). What I am looking for however is just some generic psuedo code on how to approach this problem, not somebody writing it for me or anything like that.

I feel like this should have been something I should've been able to figure out, but I am just not getting there. First I generate separate arrays for all property combinations (all `a`'s, all `b`'s, all `c`'s, all `ab`'s, all `bc`'s, etc). The thing however is that with 3 properties already you next have to add for every `a` all `b`'s, `c`'s and `bc`'s. Now, writing that out for a single property is simple enough, but writing a generic solution that does that for n-properties is just eluding me entirely.

Comment: @Teemu: Although we're speaking about 4 properties, the total number of generated items will 'just' be around 3000 (which would quite definitely not crash a modern browser, even if the number of generated items would be 10x as much). Additionally I am not sure where you get your idea from that this would be run in the browser (which is not the case, running it on application setup in node.js).

Comment: I guess I am not following how your input relates to your output or what constitutes a "combination" in your case. Why is there no `{a:2, b:4}` in your output for example? What is difference between object that have single key value and those that have multiple key/values pairs?

Comment: @MikeBrant: Regarding your first question: Because there is no {a:2} defined in the input. A multiple key/value pair input is already a defined combination of two items, which goes straight to the output if it's length is equal to the number of properties. If however we would be talking about 3 properties it would be combined with every possible value of a sole `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I really understand the requirements, but you might try a recursive solution along these lines (in pseudocode not javascript):

```
def generate(i,C):
    # C is a dictionary representing the currently defined properties
    # We are allowed to add to our set of properties from the choices input[i],input[i+1],...

    # First choose a non-conflicting set of additional properties to add
    while i<len(input):
        if all of properties in input[i] are not in C:
             Add properties in input[i] to C
             solutions.append(C)
             generate(i+1,C)
             Remove properties in input[i] from C
        i++

generate(0,{})
```

Comment: It seems to indeed be working, my brain is still having a hard time  comprehending the construction, but if it still lives up to my scrutiny tomorrow morning, then you sir are a genius for writing that out from the top of your head :D .